# jquery clean old dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

I am trying to use UI dialog to create a modal dialog.

The dialog workscorrectly, and all is well. I close the dialog using  the "X" in the corner. 
I tried using `dialog('destroy').remove();`, but then of course I can't open it again.

I think I just don't understand how to reinitialize the dialog and do not have the old values in it.

```
    function CreateWorkBoard()
{
    var jsmarty = WMCreateSmartyObject();
    var param =
    {
        MY_NAME1:GLOBAL_MY_NAME1,
        MY_NAME2:GLOBAL_MY_NAME2,
        LANG_NAME:LANGUAGE_NAME,
        BOARD_DIALOG_TITLE:WM_LANG_BOARD_DIALOG_BOARD_DIALOG_TITLE,
        BOARD_TITLE: WM_LANG_BOARD_DIALOG_BOARD_TITLE,
        COMMENT_TITLE:WM_LANG_BOARD_DIALOG_COMMENT_TITLE,
        MEMBERS_TITLE:WM_LANG_BOARD_DIALOG_MEMBERS_TITLE,
        CANCEL_BUTTON:WM_LANG_BOARD_DIALOG_CANCEL_BUTTON,
        REGISTER_BUTTON:WM_LANG_BOARD_DIALOG_REGISTER_BUTTON

    };
    jsmarty.assign('LANG', param);
    var divValue = WMSmartyFetch(jsmarty, 'createBoardDialog.tpl');
    document.getElementById('CREATE_DIALOG').innerHTML = divValue;
    jsmarty.clear_all_assign();
    //alert(document.getElementById('CREATE_DIALOG').innerHTML);
    //alert(divValue);

    //$.ui.dialog.defaults.bgiframe = true;
    //alert(document.getElementById('New_WorkBoard_Dialog').innerHTML);
    $('#New_WorkBoard_Dialog').dialog({

        autoOpen: false,
        height: 530,
        width:300,
        modal: true,
        resizable:false,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                 //$('#New_WorkBoard_Dialog').dialog('destroy');
            },
            'Register board': function() {
                var board_name=document.getElementById("name");
                var comments=document.getElementById("comment");
                Createboard(board_name,comments);
                $(this).dialog('close');

            }

        },
        close: function() {

        }
    });
    $('#New_WorkBoard_Dialog').dialog('open');

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Ra Yell said, is better to clean it before closing it, this way you don't have to worry about it when you open the dialog again.

```
$('input').val('');
```

The previous instruction worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear all input elements dynamically.

```
$("#New_WorkBoard_Dialog input[type='text']").each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).val("");
)};
```

If you prefer, you can clear it on close event of the dialog:

```
$('#New_WorkBoard_Dialog').dialog({
autoOpen: false,
height: 530,
width:300,
modal: true,
resizable:false,
buttons: {
    Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
         //$('#New_WorkBoard_Dialog').dialog('destroy');
    },
    'Register board': function() {
        var board_name=document.getElementById("name");
        var comments=document.getElementById("comment");
        Createboard(board_name,comments);
        $(this).dialog('close');

    }

},
close: function() {
    $("#New_WorkBoard_Dialog input[type='text']").each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).val("");
    )};
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to reopen it again just use this code again:

```
$('#New_WorkBoard_Dialog').dialog('open');
```

Don't bother destroying and reinitializing the dialog. There's no need for that.

Comment: It reopens this way but it does not clear the last entered values.
How can i do it withourt destroying it.

Comment: Clear the values yourself: `$('input,textarea,select').val('');`