# Jquery Clear Popup on Close

Tags: jquery, popup

I'm searching how to clear the contents of a popup on close.

I basically have a page with contacts, of which the details can be shown by clicking on an icon in the list.

So the same popup can be reused several times if I click on an icon several times.

However, when I click a second time on the icon, the data from the previous user is still there.

How can I clear that?

This question is similar to [jquery clean old dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345584/jquery-clean-old-dialog) , however, there they are looking for how to clear the form contents...

Comment: Can you show us a test page or post the code you've already tried please?

Comment: What are you using for the popup? Is it a jquery UI dialog, or something different?

Comment: Sorry, that was too little information :)... I am using the JQuery UI dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you place the result into particular div or table in the  pop up.So you can empty the content of the result's div or table and place your  content.